# In Spring, why are line numbers lost for CGLib on a POJO?

Tags: spring, exception, spring-mvc, controller, cglib

Spring MVC web app:

I have a stack trace w/o line numbers (shown at bottom).

I presume that this is due to CGLib running on the controller. But this is odd to me, the actual exception occurs in `ServerBatchRemoteRequestAcceptor`, a pojo that is not injected, not the controller. It is only created in the Controller object.

Example:

```
@Controller
class MyController {
    MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo();

    @RequestMapping("myaction")
    public void doMyAction(){
        pojo.methodToCauseNullPointerException()
    }
}
```

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at mycommons.services.batchremoteprocessor.ServerBatchRemoteRequestAcceptor.acceptRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.proxyandvpn.web.controllers.RESTServicesController.handleGenericClientRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.proxyandvpn.web.controllers.RESTServicesController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$dff24f0f.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
```

Can someone explain this behavior to me? Will every call under my Controllers be without line numbers due to CGLib?

Should I write my Controllers to an interface so that proxies are used? Is that normal? I do it for services, but have done the controllers as simple POJOs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring uses CGLIB to generate proxy objects that sit in front of some of your components/controllers. Calls to those components pass through the CGLIB proxies.  These proxies are generated a runtime, with no source code, so they have no line numbers.

You can pretty much ignore the stack trace lines that mention CGLIB, though - pretend they're not there, they should be transparent.

In your stack trace, the call to `RESTServicesController.handleGenericClientRequest` has been proxied, but the call is still getting there.  The NPE is occurring within `ServerBatchRemoteRequestAcceptor`, which is being invoked from `RESTServicesController.handleGenericClientRequest`.

However, the source code you posted has no relation to the stack trace, so it's hard to comment as to why it happened.

Answer (score 1):

I will add to this answer as I now know my problem. As is common when you don't understand a problem, I didn't ask the right question.

I had recently switched to using ANT builds instead of Eclipse builder. I didn't realize that I needed to expressly enable debugging information in the  task. I unwittingly blamed CGLib when I saw it sitting in front of this error, but all that was necessary was an ANT build modification.

Comment: How did you do it using ANT, means I am having problem with debugging because of line numbers so how to build using ANT so that it will build the line numbers also