# Why line number is not printed in exception logs generally for proxys?

Tags: java, spring, exception, proxy

Why line number is not printed for spring proxys?

Sometimes i get the excpetion in logs i see line number is not printed. I have seen mainly for spring CGLIB proxies. For example
in below stack trace i see line number is not printed for CustomerServiceBean proxy managed by spring .

```
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
at com.xeb.customer.account.CustomerServiceBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5a0112c7.getCustomerDetails(<generated>)
at com.xeb.customer.account.CustomerUtil.getCustomerDetails(CustomerUtil.java:142)
```

Any idea why ? Is there a configuration to print line number in proxies too ?

**Update :-**  I understand proxies are genertaed at run time, so it does not makes sense to print their line(if printed does not matter). But my question
how can i get the line no of exception in `CustomerServiceBean.java` which is actual class behind proxy `CustomerServiceBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5a0112c7.getCustomerDetails`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548460/in-spring-why-are-line-numbers-lost-for-cglib-on-a-pojo

Comment: Showing the complete stack trace would certainly help in identifying the location of the problem. The current stack trace extract shows only the calls from `CustomerUtil.getCustomerDetails()` into the (well tested) layers of spring code, whereas the problem is most probably within code the gets called from the method interceptors.

Answer (score 0):

These proxy classes are dynamically generated at runtime through direct byte code generation. Therefore these classes have no corresponding java source files.

While it would be technically feasible to assign (random) line numbers, this is not meaningfull.

---

If the exception is thrown within the code of your class the stack trace would contain the name of your class and the corresponding line number.

As a (hypothetical) example, based on the stack trace you provided:

```
at com.xeb.customer.account.CustomerServiceBean.getCustomerDetails(CustomerServiceBean.java:<your linenumber>)
at ...
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:...)
at ...
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
at com.xeb.customer.account.CustomerServiceBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5a0112c7.getCustomerDetails(<generated>)
at com.xeb.customer.account.CustomerUtil.getCustomerDetails(CustomerUtil.java:142)
```

Comment: But there is also an actual class behind proxy. So in my case proxy will actually call CustomerServiceBean and somewhere in my actual class i am getting error. How can i get that ?

Comment: @scottmiles the code behind the proxy as called somewhere from the `ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed`, so the line number your looking for is more near the beginning of the stack trace

Comment: in my case i just see `at com.xeb.customer.account.CustomerServiceBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5a0112c7.getCustomerDetails(<generated>)` in stack trace. No actual bean CustomerServiceBean line number is printed in trace ?